# Sitecore Patching

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to insert some new nodes in an existing node of a Sitecore configuration file.

How do I patch the default behavior of:

```
                <event name="publish:end">
                    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
                        <sites hint="list">
                            <site>website</site>
                        </sites>
                    </handler>
                </event>
```

with:

```
            <event name="publish:end">
                <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>english</site>
                        <site>chinese</site>
                        <site>german</site>
                        <site>spanish</site>
                        <site>french</site>
                        <site>italian</site>
                        <site>japanese</site>
                        <site>portuguese</site>
                        <site>russian</site>
                        <site>website</site>
                    </sites>
                </handler>
            </event>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <patch:delete />
      </sites>
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>english</site>
        <site>chinese</site>
        <site>german</site>
        <site>spanish</site>
        <site>french</site>
        <site>italian</site>
        <site>japanese</site>
        <site>portuguese</site>
        <site>russian</site>
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
</event>
```

Comment: Thanks.   I had been trying to patch:before and that didn't seem to work.   This one works!